# AppDelegate function is not loading Table view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, appdelegate

I created the simple Master Detail application for login.I deleted the MasterViewController, DetailViewController and Main.storyboard according to this tutorial:

[Login app to mysql DB [part 1]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=peY8W0xWCvw)

In AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function i made the following change

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window=[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds] ];

    /*UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
     UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
     navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;*/

    LoginTableViewController *loginTableViewController=[[LoginTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginTableViewController" bundle:nil ];

    self.navigationController =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:loginTableViewController];

    self.window.rootViewController=self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyWindow];

    return YES;
}
```

I commented this function from App Delegate function

```
  /*
    - (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController collapseSecondaryViewController:(UIViewController *)secondaryViewController ontoPrimaryViewController:(UIViewController *)primaryViewController {
.............................

    }*/
```

I created LoginTableTableViewController with xib of subclass UITableViewController.
I created LoginTableTableViewController.h

```
 #import "LoginTableViewController.h"

@interface LoginTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginTableViewController
@synthesize arraylogin,userNameTextField,passwordTextField;
bool isKeyboardVisible=FALSE;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    arraylogin=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"user name",@"password",nil];
    //set title
    self.navigationItem.title=@"Best App";

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardAppeared) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

-(void) loginAction
{
    if([userNameTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [passwordTextField.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {

        //   UIAlertView @alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] intitWithTitle:@"alert" messge:@"Please fill in all //the fields" delegate:self cancel]
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"alert" message:@"Please fill in all the fields" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        //i will use a code to connect to DB turorial

    }
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(void)keyboardAppeared
{
    if(isKeyboardVisible==false)
    {
        isKeyboardVisible=true;

        UIBarButtonItem *btnGo=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Go" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(loginAction)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=btnGo;
    }
}
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

    return [arraylogin count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifer=@"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifer];

    if (cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifer];

    }
    //cell are not selectable
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x=10;
    frame.origin.y=10;
    frame.size.height=30 ;
    frame.size.width= 200;

    UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:frame];

    label.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0];
    label.text=[arraylogin objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

    frame.origin.x=110;
    frame.size.height=90 ;
    frame.size.width= 180;

    // Configure the cell
    if(indexPath.row==0)
    {//username part
        userNameTextField=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

        userNameTextField.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDefault;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:userNameTextField];
    }
    else{//password part
        passwordTextField=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        passwordTextField.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDefault;
        passwordTextField.secureTextEntry=YES;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:passwordTextField];
    }
    return cell;
}


/*
 // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
 return YES;
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to support editing the table view.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
 // Delete the row from the data source
 [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
 } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
 // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
 }
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to support rearranging the table view.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
 return YES;
 }
 *
 /

 /*
 #pragma mark - Table view delegate

 // In a xib-based application, navigation from a table can be handled in -tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 // Navigation logic may go here, for example:
 // Create the next view controller.
 <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:<#@"Nib name"#> bundle:nil];

 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

 // Push the view controller.
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
 }
 */
-(void) viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.arraylogin=nil;
    self.userNameTextField=nil;
    self.passwordTextField=nil;
}
/*
 #pragma mark - Navigation

 // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
 // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 }
 */

@end
```

This program should be executing and show out like in this image

[image].

Execution stops program on some thread of main class function how i can remove this error and get the required output?You can download sample code from this link for correction.https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5pNDpbvZ8SnV3Zab3VPM1B0a0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Go to BreakPoint Navigator, add an "exception breakpoint", run the project and you might get more useful information bout the error.

Comment: I have already ran project by adding an "exception breakpoint" and break point navigation .The useful information is program run though appdelegate function but when reaches class of main function their is execution stoping thread .so the app doesnot executes the LoginTableViewController.h

Answer (score 1):

Your project is still specifying that a "Main" storyboard should be loaded.  Edit your Info.plist file to remove the storyboard entry and it will get you past the current error.

(If you include error messages from your debug console when asking a question, it makes it easier on anyone trying to help.  For example: "*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle*".)

Comment: I have deleted "Main" storyboard from info.plist .still it is not working .